# Is it possible to prevent buffer overflow with strcpy in C++ using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, strcpy

Code that copies the text from source to destination and then prints it as a buffer

```
void strcpy(char *destination, char *source, int bufferSize) { 
    int i = 0;
    while (i < bufferSize && *source != 0) { 
        *destination = *source;  
        destination += 1;
        source += 1;
        i += 1;
    }

    *destination = 0;
}
char *text = "Tomek";
char buffer[1024];

strcpy(buffer, text, 1024);
```

Comment: If the source c style string is too long. the `*destination = 0;` will be a buffer overflow as it writes one past the end.

Comment: don't use c-style strings in c++ please

Comment: While the OP has tagged C++, this is entirely C concepts. Also, `source` should be `const char *`.

Comment: @Chris there are still people who believe that the best way to learn C++ is to start with C.  The more those languages diverge, the less true that becomes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely you want [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) which does *approximately* this.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) page on `strncpy`:

> 1. Copies at most count characters of the character array pointed to
>    by src (including the terminating null character, but not any of the
>    characters that follow the null character) to character array pointed
>    to by dest.

For fun, consider the following definition of your function, renamed slightly. Do you understand what's going on with the pointers?

```
void strcpy_(char *dest, const char *src, size_t buf_size) {
    buf_size--;
    while (buf_size-- && *src && (*dest++ = *src++));
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

Comment: actually strlcpy. Using strncpy for this is actually a common cause of bugs because strncpy does not null-terminate the output.

Comment: I just started to learn pointers and I do understand the basics minimum for now.

Comment: It's actually interesting how the while loop looks in your code. May I ask why this part of the code is included in a condition instead? `(*dest++ = *src++)`

Comment: Taking advantage of the short-circuiting behavior of `&&` and that `(*dest++ = *src++)` will not return `0`.